# Calculate the two rows following a row with a certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with ones and NaN values and would like to calculate the two rows following the ones to two and three.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"b" : [1,None,None,None,None,1,None,None,None]})
print(df)

      b
0   1.0
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   1.0
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
```

Like this:

```
      b
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   1.0
6   2.0
7   3.0
8   NaN
```

I know i can use `df.loc[df['b']==1]` to retrive the ones but i dont know how to calculate the two rows below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a group variable where each `1` in b starts a new group, then forward fill 2 rows for each group, and do a `cumsum`:

```
g = (df.b == 1).cumsum()
df.b.groupby(g).apply(lambda g: g.ffill(limit = 2).cumsum())

#0    1.0
#1    2.0
#2    3.0
#3    NaN
#4    NaN
#5    1.0
#6    2.0
#7    3.0
#8    NaN
#Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Comment: ++ I didn't know about `limit` parameter

Comment: @MaxU Thank you! I didn't know this before either. Just discovered it. :)

Answer (score 2):

One without groupby:

```
temp = df.ffill(limit=2).cumsum()
temp-temp.mask(df.b.isnull()).ffill(limit=2)+1

Out[91]: 
     b
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  NaN
4  NaN
5  1.0
6  2.0
7  3.0
8  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your current line of thinking, you simply need the index of the rows after the 1s and set to appropriate values:

```
df.loc[np.where(df['b']==1)[0]+1, 'b'] = 2
df.loc[np.where(df['b']==1)[0]+2, 'b'] = 3
```